# Bundle Name, Executable Name, Product Name...anything else?

Tags: iphone, xcode

Bundle Name, Executable Name, Product Name... any more??

can someone please help clarify the use of each of these in Xcode on an iPhone project?  They never fail to confuse the living bajezus out of me...and Im tired of getting them wrong.

Someone please explain... why the hell do we need this many different naming schemes for one app environment? and what do I use each of these for so I can stick them in the right cubby hole in my head?

Comment: I think we might be able to better help you if we had a specific problem you ran into.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

If you look at an info.plist, it goes something like this:

```
Bundle Display Name - ${PRODUCT_NAME}
Executable File - ${EXECUTABLE_NAME}
Bundle Name - ${PRODUCT_NAME}
```

So you can see, that normally PRODUCT_NAME gives you the same name for the bundle and what the user sees.

In some cases you may want a more complex display name that is not suitable for naming things like bundles or executables, which is why you can change them independently - but you don't have to.  The default is that PRODUCT_NAME is the same name as the project name, but you can also override it in the build settings.

You shouldn't be changing the way they are set up in info.plist, unless you have a very good reason... just change PRODUCT_NAME.

Comment: OK!  Finally some clarity.  

So my final message to the memory is just to remember... only change PRODUCT_NAME  ( and best to do it in the target info window I assume ).

Thanks!

Comment: Are there any other flags apart from these three that can be helpful?

Comment: There's a ton of potentially useful settings you can enable in the plist, you should really google for a full list to see what is possible.

Answer (score 50):

**Bundle name** - is folder name, where your app (including executable file and all resources) will be stored (Cool Program.app).

**Executable name** - is a program binary name, i.e. Cool Program.app/CoolProgram

**Bundle display name** - is what will be shown on iPhone screen, for example Cool Prog (since Cool Program probably will not fit on Springboard).

And, Apple claims, that Bundle Display name must correspond to Bundle name, i.e. you cannot use bundle name TheApplication, and bundle display name Something Other

Comment: At least we have some apps rejected for that reason, 2 years ago. Maybe now it is changed, or app reviewers are not that angry :)

Comment: Bundle Display name can be different to Bundle name now, my app is not rejected for this reason.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a application with UI(eg: Calculator) then most of the above will be same and doesn't matter much but if your project output is just a bundle(some engine) then you can have different executables(apps/frontend with UI which uses ur bundle as backend) of your bundle that you can specify using different executable name. And ideally as Kendall said bundle name will be same as product name. Refer Xcode Build System Guide for better understanding. Hope this helps. :-).

Answer (score 0):

There is also ${TARGET_NAME} - for example if you have one project that makes multiple targets with different 'Bundle Display Name's.

Answer (score -2):

According to Apple.com docs, it's exactly the opposite of what you'd expect.

The "Display name" is the *ACTUAL* name of the bundle.

But the "Bundle name" is just the short "DISPLAY" name.

Actual cut/paste from Apple.com:

> CFBundleName (Recommended, Localizable) The actual name of the bundle.
>
> CFBundleDisplayName (Recommended, Localizable) The short display name of the bundle.

Ugh.

Comment: The "Bundle display name" is the short name.