# iOS Pinterest insert nil object

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, pinterest

After having setup my app like the pinterest tutorial suggests (https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/sdks/ios/) I tried to pin a simple image and failed. It returns the following error:

```
NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[3]'
```

Even if I use the pinterest SDK [example code][2].

```
[PDKPin pinWithImageURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://about.pinterest.com/sites/about/files/logo.jpg"]
    link:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.pinterest.com"]
    suggestedBoardName:@"Tooty McFruity"
    note:@"The Pinterest Logo" withSuccess: ^{
        NSLog(@"successfully pinned pin");
    }
    andFailure: ^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"pin it failed");
    }];
```

What am I doing wrong? Or is this a SDK Bug?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out myself. My plist file was missing the BundleDisplayName. In order to solve this problem you just need to add it to the plist file.

Comment: raw key, CFBundleDisplayName

Comment: Further discussion on this field [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3465924/885189).