# Space in iOS app name is not showing

Tags: ios

My bundle display name is "Standford 2015" in Xcode but it is showing on my iPhone as "Standford2015" when it's installed.

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: How did you setup the bundle name? Which property in plist?

Comment: Property name in plist is "Bundle display name", I changed it to "Standford 2015" through XCode.

Comment: I resolved this issue. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46337691/bundle-display-name-missing-space-characters/46399849).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bundle display name missing space characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46337691/bundle-display-name-missing-space-characters)

Answer (score 62):

For iOS 11 you can open the info.plist as source code and use `&#x2007;` instead of spaces

Comment: Try follow the steps in this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46337691/bundle-display-name-missing-space-characters

Comment: I used this solution today and it worked, thank you

Comment: On iOS 14.7.1 is working for me. I used ```&#x0020;```

Comment: not worked for me

Comment: this does not work

Answer (score 42):

1. Open the info.plist file as SourceCode.
2. Use &#x2007 ; as separator for the space in CFBundleDisplayName.

Example

```
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>App&#x2007;Name</string>
```

Comment: It seems like double space

Comment: not worked for me

Comment: this does not work

Answer (score 15):

I'd actually recommend using `&#x0020;` instead of `&#x2007;`. The latter is a "figure space" which looks awkward compared to the former, which is simply a space. See comparison below:

[image: Comparison]

Comment: &#x0020; doesnt work for me

Comment: Using 0020 allows iOS to show several more characters of your app name than 2007.

Comment: neither of these work

Answer (score 7):

In your localized InfoPlist.string DO NOT use spaces but instead use unicode character "No-break space" :

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm

so your line in InfoPlist.string should look like :

`"CFBundleDisplayName" = "My\U00A0app";`

Comment: In your InfoPlist.strings, use the character `\U2007` ("figure space") rather than the "no-break space".

Comment: Thanks, in my info.plist I loaded the name from my build settings, `&#x2007;` did not work for me but `\U2007` did.

Answer (score 4):

I resolved this issue by replacing space with unicode symbol like NB space.

I presented a little instruction in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46337691/bundle-display-name-missing-space-characters).

Answer (score 3):

This could also be caused by the app icon title character limit. e.g. if app name exceeds 12 chars (I think), spaces are removed on build.

Comment: This is the correct answer. 13 characters worked for me (iOS 17)

Answer (score 0):

Use plist `CFBundleDisplayName` to set the space below the icon.

More info: 
[What's the difference between "bundle display name" and "bundle name" in cocoa application's info plist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465792/whats-the-difference-between-bundle-display-name-and-bundle-name-in-cocoa-a)

Comment: How is this different from what I said?

Comment: @matt notice the link to more info which explains other edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using 3 spaces in app name string (in place of one space) in `Info.plist` and it works for me:

```xml
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>App   Name</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: `&#x2002;`

`&#x2007;` looks like 2 or 3 spaces

Answer (score 0):

For **Info.plist** this is what worked for me: **`&#x2002;`**

and for localized **InfoPlist.strings** this is what worked for me: **`\U2002`**

and I tried all the options above.

Answer (score -1):

Possible workaround: use localizable InfoPlist.strings file with content:

```
/* Localized versions of Info.plist keys */
"CFBundleDisplayName" = "Standford 2015";
```