# How can I add spaces to the app name

Tags: ios, xcode8

I'm trying to add spaces to my app name and even though my Bundle display name contains spaces they won't show up on the simulator.

Does anybody know how do achieve that?

Thank you very much

Comment: where did you change it? Info.plist or in General Tab.

Comment: Try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43098355/1725535)

Comment: Okay just as a quick info, Apple just removed the space because the name was too long. So everything's fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Open project "Info".
>
> Add a property "Bundle Display Name" into "Custom iOS Target
>   Properties". (as "Key")
>
> Enter the display name, that will be shown on iPhone/iPad screen under
>   an app icon. (as "Value")

And also you should delete previously installed app and reinstall it.
[image]

Comment: This also doesn't work, it still shows the name without a space in between the words

Comment: I'm sorry it does work but apparently my name reached some sort of character limit which caused the words to move together but after adjusting the name a bit it shows the name with spaces, thank you

Comment: iPhone's font is not fixed width. So it depends which character is used.
For example, the character of "M" or "W" take more space.In contrast, "i" or "t" need narrower space.

Answer (score 21):

From iOS 11, if app name consists of more than 12 characters(smaller devices), OS will automatically remove spaces.

I don't see any workaround for that as of now.

Comment: There is a workaround by adding non-breaking space  (" ")

Comment: Thought I was going crazy until i found this answer - nothing in other answers was working for me.  There also seems to be some dependence on screen size - spaces are not removed from my app name on larger screens (like iPhone 12)

Answer (score 16):

Open .plist as SourceCode and then in xml format use &#x2007; instead of space. You can find appname under xml tag "CFBundleDisplayName" or you can add this tag. e.g App&#x2007;name

Comment: From all the answers, this is what worked for me, thanks!

Comment: Confirmed! Though i dont know how to do edit info.plist source code in xcode. i used android studio since im using this for flutter.

Answer (score 1):

Goto `build settings`, Under `product name`, set the desired name with spaces. It will work fine.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From the iOS 11 onwards, Please follow below ToDo I have did and worked well !!
[image: Link]

Answer (score 1):

Use this below string in your project which will give the perfect app name with proper single character space:

```
Demo App
```

**The upper code is tested and verified in different environment setups and app name set in .xcconfig file.**

You can also try with default config if it is working or not.

**Note: You don't need to type otherwise it won't work, this will only work if you use my given string, so use it and modify only words, not the space.**