# Bundle display name missing space characters

Tags: ios, objective-c, cfbundledisplayname

When I give Bundle display name with space as "A B C D", I get the app name as "ABCD". This happens only on the iOS 11.I tried override name"CFBundleDisplayName" in my InfoPlist.string and use special unicode character \U00A0 (No-break space) and it doesn't help me.

Answer (score 84):

This is because of a change Apple made in iOS 11 for truncating for longer app names.  If the name is longer than 12 characters, the spaces will be removed.  Otherwise, they'll still exist.

For example, `Guide book app` will become `Guidebookapp`, but `Gui boo app` will stay as `Gui boo app`.

Using unicode `&#x2007;` ([FIGURE SPACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2007/index.htm)) works because it isn't an ascii space.  I would be hesitant to use this as a solution because it seems reasonable that Apple would "fix" this bug and remove `&#x2007;` for apps with names longer than 12 characters.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/77832

Comment: Finally an actual explanation of what is happening! Thanks! However strange that there is still no official documentation from Apple about this.

Comment: Thanks. It kept the spaces for 14 characters for me too on iPhone 11 Pro.

Comment: This could be an attempt by Apple to sanitize homoglyph abuse. I use an ASCII7 conversion function in my web applications to strip UTF8 from values that are used as keys.

Answer (score 57):

I have the same issue. Only on iOS 11. On lower iOS version this issue isn't appeared.

I resolved this with:

1. Open info.plist as Source code(right click, open as...)
2. Find CFBundleDisplayName
3. Replace normal space with unicode `&#x2007;`

That's all. After that display name shows with space.

#### UPDATED:

`&#x2007;` works only when typed in *.plist. Can't be inserted in `Display name` in Xcode project settings;

Comment: Hi, did you opened a ticket into http://bugreport.apple.com regarding this?

Comment: @AndreaLeganza, no.

Comment: So is this a feature or a bug? In the apple developer forums I could only find threads describing the issue and this workaround, however no official explanation.

Comment: @Dominic, why can it be feature?  There is no official information about it. Therefore, it's a bug.

Comment: Note that `&#x2007;` is displayed as a double space in the Settings app on iOS 11 and the Home screen on iOS 9 & 10.

Comment: @DaveAlden, Yes, it is.

Comment: Found thread on Apple Forum reason: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/77832.

Comment: simply putting two spaces in the Bundle display name achieves the same effect.

Comment: What about in multiple target context using "InfoPlist.strings" to translate app names ?

Comment: It's make app displayed as a double space on name app title of notification

Comment: @bkit4u, ofc. Like the app name, too. It was notified above.

Answer (score 16):

It works for me when I replace space with [FIGURE SPACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2007/browsertest.htm)   in `InfoPlist.strings` manually or with a script.

Comment: just copy-paste space from your message and finally got space

Comment: Very odd. It works at my end by copy/pasting "your" space...

Answer (score 6):

Edit info.plist as source code but use `&#32;` instead of `&#x2007;`.
`&#x2007;` looks like 2 spaces.

Comment: ` &#32;` works great on iOS 9.0 but doesn't work in present versions of iOS (11+).

Answer (score 2):

In my case this value was missing from info.plist file so I just add the following to it:

```
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
```

[image: should look like this]

Answer (score -4):

Give More Space in Bundle Display Name
like 
abc    def    abcdef
[image]