# Bundle display name(CFBundleDisplayName) missing space characters in iOS 11

Tags: ios, iphone, ios11

When I give **Bundle display name** with space as "my app display name", I get the app name as ("myappdisplay..."). This happens only on the iOS 11 , in iOS 10 and below(<) it is showing properly as ("my app displa...") .

I tried to override name "CFBundleDisplayName" in my Info.Plist with unicode character   ,working fine at iOS 11 but it is showing double space in iOS 9 and 10.

Another question is this a feature or a bug ? If it is feature , Can you provide me apple official link.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bundle display name missing space characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46337691/bundle-display-name-missing-space-characters)

Answer (score 1):

1. Open info.plist as Source code(right click, open as...)
2. Find CFBundleDisplayName
3. Replace normal space with unicode `&#x2007;`

`&#x2007;` works only when typed in *.plist. Can't be inserted in Display name in Xcode project settings;

From: [Bundle display name missing space characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46337691/bundle-display-name-missing-space-characters)
Developer apple: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/77832

You could check other answers for this post, they explain the reason.

Comment: Ya I tried this(&#x2007;) . But it is showing double space in iOS 9 and 10.

Comment: i think you are adding space as well in CFBundleDisplayName.

Comment: @user3828620 try &#x20; , some people tell that &#x2007; doubles space

Comment: Hi  Zeshan Arif , I did not your answer . Idid as below . 
 <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
 <string>app&#x2007;name</string><key>CFBundleExecutable</key>

Comment: &#x2007; looks "wider" than the normal space to me