Why Does My iOS App Name Show as "MyTestApp" Instead of "My Test App"?
I'm developing a .NET MAUI application for iOS. I encountered an issue with the display of my app's name on the device's home screen.
If I set the app name as "My Test App", it appears as "MyTestApp" (without spaces) on the device.
However, if I set the name as "My App", the spaces are preserved, and it displays correctly.
I checked my Info.plist file, and the CFBundleDisplayName and CFBundleName values are set correctly. This issue is consistent across both the simulator and physical devices.
My questions:
Is this a known limitation or behavior in iOS where spaces in app names are handled differently based on the name's length or structure?
Could this be a bug in the .NET MAUI framework

check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46337691/bundle-display-name-missing-space-characters/46399849
