# How to update my APP name from PayPal prompt?

Tags: braintree

I have integrated BrainTree payment SDK. And trying to login PayPal sandbox account for further payment.
One prompt will show up each time I trigger  payPalDriver.authorizeAccount，
the prompt content is :
"XXXX" Wants to Use "paypal.com" to Sign In.

My question is can I custom XXX in the prompt? And How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XXXX` is pulled from `CFBundleDisplayName` which is in the [Info.plist](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html) file. This [Stack Overflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3465924/7851516) goes into more detail regarding Bundle Names for iOS apps.

Comment: Thank you. But I think the correct answer is CFBundleName, not the CFBundleDisplayName. There are two different items.

Comment: @Kevin The purpose of `CFBundleDisplayName` is to display the name to the user ([link to Apple's docs here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-110725)). `CFBundleName` specifies the short name of the bundle, which may be displayed to users in situations such as the _absence of a value_ for CFBundleDisplayName. `CFBundleName` should be less than 16 characters long.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right, that's maybe related to BrainTree's solution.