# Unable to change flutter app name from 'Runner'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I built an app and I want to name it as 'MyApp'. I went through the 'Release app' documentation for flutter and changes Display Name to MyApp. I also tried to change it in Info.plist > BundleName to MyApp but no luck.

When I launch my app it shoes 'Runner'. I am not sure where to change this so it changes on my iPhone.

---

Update: When I install it from Runner it shows the correct name but when I do it from Android Studio it changes back to Runner

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between `CFBundleDisplayName` and `CFBundleName`. You can read more about it here: [What's the difference between "bundle display name" and "bundle name" in cocoa application's info plist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465792/whats-the-difference-between-bundle-display-name-and-bundle-name-in-cocoa-a)

Probably you should specify `CFBundleDisplayName`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that cleaned the build cache could solve your problem. At the root of your project run `flutter clean`

Comment: I did do that a few random times but the result comes to be the same

Comment: Any more ideas please?