# Swift -GDPR Consent form returns Error: invalid app name

Tags: ios, swift, gdprconsentform

For some reason when I try to load the GDPR Consent form I keep getting the error:

> Error: invalid app name.

It happens here :

```
form.load { [weak self](_ error: Error?) -> Void in
                    print("Load complete.")

    if let error = error {

        // *** HERE IS THE ERROR ***

        print("Error loading form: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return
    }
```

When I do a global search for `invalid app name` I get brought to the `consentform.html` file:

```
// Set app name.
var appName = formInfo['app_name'] || '';
if (appName.length <= 0) {
  formLoadCompleted('Error: invalid app name.');
}
```

This tells some value from either the `googleservice-plist` or my `info.plist` or something else isn't being read correctly but I don't know which value to look at.

Inside my `info.plist` I have the `GADApplicationIdentifier` correctly set:

[image]

**Why is my app's name coming up as nil?**

```
PACConsentInformation.sharedInstance.debugGeography = .EEA

    PACConsentInformation
        .sharedInstance
        .requestConsentInfoUpdate(forPublisherIdentifiers: ["pub-MY_PublisherID"]) { [weak self](error) in

            if let error = error { return }
            PACConsentInformation.sharedInstance.isRequestLocationInEEAOrUnknown {

                if PACConsentInformation.sharedInstance.consentStatus == PACConsentStatus.unknown {

                    guard let privacyUrl = URL(string: "My_Privacy_URL"),
                        let form = PACConsentForm(applicationPrivacyPolicyURL: privacyUrl) else {
                            return
                    }
                    form.shouldOfferPersonalizedAds = true
                    form.shouldOfferNonPersonalizedAds = true
                    form.shouldOfferAdFree = true

                    form.load { [weak self](_ error: Error?) -> Void in
                        print("Load complete.")

                        if let error = error {

                            // *** HERE IS THE ERROR ***

                            print("Error loading form: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                            return
                        }

                        // ...
                    }

                    return
                }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add dig deep to find out the problem but the issue was the `CFBundleDisplayName` or better yet the `Bundle Display Name`(red) in the `info.plist` was blank:

[image]

If the `Bundle Display Name` (red) is blank then the `GDPR Consent` form will return an error. You can either manually type in your app's name

OR

just **DELETE** the entire (red)`Bundle Display Name` k/v field. If you delete it then then the `GDPR Consent` will resort to use the `Bundle Name`(yellow).

**Whatever you do DON'T make the mistake and delete the**`Bundle Name`(yellow) .

Follow these 2 answers for an explanation between the `Bundle Display Name` and the `Bundle Name`:

[Bundle Display Name explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26462112/4833705)

[Bundle Display Name with pics](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34968739/4833705)

Comment: Strange behavior indeed by Admob! My app's name shows up just fine on Springboard yet I got this error too.