# App Store - Bundle Display Name too long?

Tags: xcode, validation, app-store

Getting a bundle display name length too long when trying the validate the archive to upload to the App Store.

[image]

Where is the Bundle Display Name stored? Unless I am confused I think my display name is only 8 characters long???

Here is the info.plist entry.

[image]

Comment: Here's how you can change it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34968739/3151675

Comment: Many thanks - I was using the info.plist but clearly got it incorrect.

Comment: Made that change and still getting the same error. Bundle display name = AbcdefghiJK

The name is 11 characters - where is it getting the 399 from!

Comment: All you have shown us is a photo of an Xcode dialog. Show _screenshots_ or _code_ and show us how _you_ think the bundle display name gets set. Best way is to open the archived built app and look right at the Info.plist and the corresponding strings file(s).

Comment: I have added the info.plist to the original question as couldn't work out how to add it in as a comment.

Comment: I am still getting the same 399 character error which is erroneous. The Bundle creator OS Type code switched to ???? so has been reset back to APPL. The Bundle display name is 8 characters and matches the project and the App title on the iPhone.

Comment: I suspect you are showing us the wrong info plist? This is some framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are showing the wrong *Info.plist*. There are two types: the app has Bundle OS Type Code `APPL` and Bundle Creator OS Type Code `????`, while a framework has Bundle OS Type Code `FMWK` and Bundle Creator OS Type Code `????`.

So apparently what you've found is some framework *Info.plist*. Moreover, have now lamed it by changing the Bundle Creator OS Type Code to a wrong value.

You need to fix this one so it work again, and then go find the real one, the one belonging to the app. My guess is that you have lamed *that* one in some way too.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Which of the two options you describe - Bundle OS Type Code and Bundle Creator OS Type Code should I be using? How to I reset/repair the Info.plist when I have located it? Did a clean on the file system and then got a better quality of error message saying that there was a corrupt character in the plist??? Still get the 399 length error when the bundle name length is 8!

Comment: I believe I've answered to the full extent possible given the material you've provided. You've messed up this info.plist and I'm guessing you've messed up the other one(s) but that's all that can be said at this distance.

Comment: I am sure the Info.plist if the culprit and many thanks on honing in on it.

Comment: This Project has got into a real mess with its info.plist and will start a new question with all the associated detail.

Answer (score 0):

you can open info.plist by text editor and check the bundle display name string. sometimes Xcode cannot display it completely

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: sorry @Community, this is the right approach to troubleshooting... From the other answers, it sounds like you need to look for **every** `Info.plist` in your project (there could be one for each bundle in your project).