# Xcode 4: How to change ${EXECUTABLE_NAME} variable's value?

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to find where is ${EXECUTABLE_NAME} global variable defined in xcode 4.2

Comment: look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437330/bundle-name-executable-name-product-name-anything-else

Comment: not useful. I want to find this variable in xcode. I already know what it is.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

[Your target] -> [Build settings] -> [Product name]

Comment: this is ${PRODUCT_NAME} not ${EXECUTABLE_NAME}

Comment: `EXECUTABLE_NAME` is generated from [PRODUCT_NAME][EXECUTABLE_PREFIX][EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX]. Details here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html

Comment: I dont think so above answer is correct as my product name XYZ and executable is still ABC.app

Comment: Is it possible to change the Executable name without changing product name?

Comment: question is about changing $(EXECUTABLE_NAME) macro.
not chaging ${PRODUCT_NAME} macro
executable name field in plist is generated from $(EXECUTABLE_NAME)
but where is the $(EXECUTABLE_NAME) macro ??

Answer (score 13):

Adding to above accurate answer

Edit:
Targets -> [Your Target Name] -> Build Settings -> Packaging -> Product Name

You can write specific String for Product Name or just copy $(TARGET_NAME) to make same name with '[Your Target Name]'

So your Product Name will be: 'Your Target Name.app'

Answer (score 4):

It's possible to set `EXECUTABLE_NAME` as user-defined setting.

Comment: How can we do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think @catlan's answer was supposed to be the accepted answer to the OP's question.
Go to Build Settings, click the + sign to add a User-Defined Setting, and enter EXECUTABLE_NAME as key with your custom exe name as value.
Note that this changes the name of the exe under MacOS, along with the entry in Info.plist.
(Sorry @catlan, I couldn't add comment to your answer, as I don't have enough reputation points yet.)

Comment: Need code formatting