# This bundle is invalid. The executable name, as reported by CFBundleExecutable

Tags: xcode

I need to upload an app that has a `*` in its name, but when I try to upload it to ItunesConnect I get this error

> This bundle is invalid. The executable name, as reported by
>   CFBundleExecutable in the Info.plist file, may not contain any of
>   these characters: []{}parenthesis.+*"

I need to keep the `*` but how can I edit my info.plist to be accepted?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The app name is set by `CFBundleDisplayName` and the executable name is set by `CFBundleExecutable` in your `Info.plist`-file. They do not have to be equal.

The `CFBundleDisplayName` and `CFBundleExecutable` has the default value of `${PRODUCT_NAME}`, but you can enter any string you want.

So:

1. Change your product name to change the `${EXECUTABLE_NAME}`, removing `*`. See [Xcode 4: How to change ${EXECUTABLE_NAME} variable's value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9528679/xcode-4-how-to-change-executable-name-variables-value)
2. Edit `CFBundleDisplayName` in the `Info.plist` file to the desired value. Here you can add `*`.